# iox xml parser use NSXMLParser escape

Tags: ios, xml, nsxmlparser

I try to use ios nsxmlparser to parser xml content,but server of response to be returned,not a 
element style,only is < and >
for example,
<NewDataSet>
        <Table>
hello
 </Table>
            </NewDataSet>
I want to get table element of content,hello,but nsxmlparser not call startELement of table.

Answer (score 0):

You should overwrite the NSXMLParser. Try the following code.

```c
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"NewDataSet"]) {
        NSLog(@"Entry into NewDataSet");
    }else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Table"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Entry into Table");
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    result = string;
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
}

- (void)getResult{
    NSString * xmlstr=@"<NewDataSet> <Table> hello </Table> </NewDataSet>";
    NSData* xmldata= [xmlstr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSXMLParser *m_parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmldata];

    [m_parser setDelegate:self];

    BOOL flag = [m_parser parse];
 }
```